# Expected value of a quasi-geometric distribution whose event probability increases with failed attempts

Tags: probability

Playing "Rim World", I noticed a geometric variable, but whose individual event probability increases with each attempt (or with time).  So I first model it with a simple probability, having a single failure parameter $q$.  The $n$th event has probability $1-q^n$ to succeed.  The probability to suceed at event $n$ is thus

\begin{equation}
P(n) = \left( \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} q^k \right) \cdot (1-q^n)
\end{equation}

My question is, what is the expected value of that random variable ?
Here is what I got so far :

\begin{align}
E[n] &= \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot \left( \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} q^k \right) \cdot (1-q^n)\\
     &= \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot \left( q^{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k} \right) \cdot (1-q^n)\\
     &= \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot q^{(n-1)\cdot n} \cdot (1-q^n)\\
     &= \left( \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot q^{(n-1)\cdot n} \right)
     -  \left( \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot q^{(n-1)\cdot n^2} \right) \\
\end{align}
Now I'd like to do, $\zeta = q^n$ and $\xi = q^{n^2}$,
\begin{align}
E[n] &= \left( \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot \zeta^{(n-1)} \right)
     -  \left( \sum_{n\ge1} n\cdot \xi^{(n-1)} \right) \\
     &= \frac{1}{(1-\zeta)^2} - \frac{1}{(1-\xi)^2}\\
\end{align}
But $\zeta$ and $\xi$ depends on $n$, so that's not a valid way of computing that.  How would you do it ?  Thank you for suggestions !

Comment: what is the problem with $\mathbb{E}[P(n)]$ depending on $n$?

Comment: I meant $\zeta = q^n$ depending on $n$, which make changing $\sum n \zeta^{n-1}$ to $\frac{1}{(1-\zeta)^2}$ completely wrong.  I shouldn't have bothered to type it in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a small error in your calculation:  $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k = \frac{(n-1)n}{2},$$ not $(n-1)n$.

That said, expressions of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n q^{n^2}$$ are not known to have an elementary closed form, so there is not much hope for solving for the expectation.

Comment: You could get a good approximation by taking $M$ terms of the finite sum and estimating the rest as $\int_M^\infty x q^{x^2} dx = \frac{-q^{M^2}}{2 \log(q)}$. If $|q|$ is not too close to $1$ then it will not take very many terms for this to be accurate.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot that $\frac{1}{2}$ factor...  Well that's too bad there's no solution.  Thanks to Ian for that nice approximation idea !